# Sugarcrm date not showing properly

Tags: php, datetime, sugarcrm

**SCENARIO**

So I've custom object where I've three fields called start_date, end_date and booking_expire_time(for an event).

My dates are coming from Magento in form of String ofc, I already have logged so they are coming like

```
Thu Aug 30 09:46:16 2018 [8779][ffba8854-e7c0-11e6-85b6-06ec5399a877][FATAL] $start_date - 08/30/2018 11:59 AM
Thu Aug 30 09:46:16 2018 [8779][ffba8854-e7c0-11e6-85b6-06ec5399a877][FATAL] $event_endt_time - 08/31/2018 11:59 AM
Thu Aug 30 09:46:16 2018 [8779][ffba8854-e7c0-11e6-85b6-06ec5399a877][FATAL] $booking_expire_time - 08/30/2018 12:59 PM
```

Which is correct and same which I've chosen in Magento

And I'm storing it like following in that bean.

```
            $st = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y H:i A",$start_date);
            $eventBean->start_date = date_format($st, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $en = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y H:i A",$event_end_time);
            $eventBean->event_end_time = date_format($en, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $ex = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y H:i A",$booking_expire_time);
            $eventBean->booking_expire_time = date_format($ex, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**ISSUE**

There is no problem for saving except when I go to the UI and check date and time, the date and time are different.
I tried changing user timezone and storing it again but it is still same, I tried setting the timezone to UTC in User settings but still, the same thing is happening.
I've logged the date time which getting retrieved in code and it prints following for start date and end date

```
 DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-08-30 11:59:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2018-08-31 11:59:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )
```

[image: For the UI date please check Image]

**EDIT**

Timezone setting

[image: Timezone settings screenshot]

PHPInfo from Diagnostic Tool
[image: PHPInfo]

Comment: So looks like in the backend your datetimes are alright. I'm not familiar with SugarCRM but does the frontend code maybe do some kind of manipulation of the dates which come from the backend? Or the template code?

Comment: @BotondBéres Yea, I'm checking but couldn't find anything I only know they have provided a setting at user management to change the timezone, so I initially thought based on that it will convert automatically but it's not happening.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the timezone in the user's profile, just to be certain?

Comment: @Reisclef Please check the image

Comment: Thanks. What version of SugarCRM are you running, and what is the PHP configured timezone?

Comment: @Reisclef I'm using About SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 8.1.0 (Build 135) (Summer '18), and I'm not on a local instance, it's production instance so I don't know how to check PHP configuration, though meanwhile, I will check config file of sugar if there is any timezone setting there. There is no setting for timezone in config.php it only have related to formats.

Comment: You can export the PHP.ini file via Admin->Diagnostics.

Comment: @Reisclef I've added a screenshot in the question of phpinfo.hmtl which got downloaded, I did not get php.ini file but I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. So now... Where is that logic that calls Magento? Next step would be to identify what the context of the request is.

Comment: I'm not calling it from Sugar, I'm pushing it via Magento to Sugar via REST, and above is the log i.e dates coming from Magento and how I'm putting it in my eventbean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179327/discussion-between-reisclef-and-indrajeet-latthe).

Comment: @Reisclef 
I forgot to tell you the date which is coming is not UTC though, it's GMT -4:00 for NY,is that causing problem?